# how to truncate certain columns to X number of characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with some columns having large sentences.

How do I truncate the columns to say 50 characters max?

current df:

```
a                     b     c
I like data science   1     2
```

new truncated df for ONLY column `a`:

```
a             b     c
I like data   1     2
```

(The above is an example sentence I made up)

Comment: Do you think `df['a'] = df['a'].str[:50]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific column:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str[:50]
```